# Wildcard targets in a Makefile when wildcard is part of a string

Tags: makefile

Makefile :

```
-- Makefile --
q_abc :
    @echo abc
q_def :
    @echo def
q_ghi :
    @echo ghi
-- execution --
$make q_abc
abc
$make q_def
def
```

How can I compact the Makefile?

```
q_% :
    @echo %
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Do you really mean `make abc` or do you mean `make q_abc` ?

Comment: @G.M. Ah, thank you. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'stem' of the pattern (i.e. the bit that matched the '%' wildcard) is represented by [`$*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002a-_0028automatic-variable_0029) in the commands part of the recipe.  So try something like...

```
q_%:
    @echo $*
```